# Polyfill using browserlist in Gatsby always provided

Tags: javascript, gatsby, babel-preset-env

I was experimenting with Gatsby and polyfills using browserlist, which is supported by Gatsby ([doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/)).

Using the default browserlist config, I get the expected result which creates polyfills for IE11 and a working alert. See my [github repo example](https://github.com/askibinski/browserlist-ie11-demo). The site is currently available [here at Netlify](https://gifted-almeida-5cfb2a.netlify.com/).

So, I can see in the produciton code how the arrow functions and the array.prototype.find function are polyfilled. Nothing weird so far.

Now, if I change the browserlist to `last 2 Chrome versions` and build production I would expect that the polyfill for the array find() method would dissappear since it is supported by chrome. However, I believe I can still find the same polyfills (from core-js) in `app-2934fab61c547573181d.js`:

```
    dRSK: function(t, e, n) {
        "use strict";
        var r = n("XKFU")
          , o = n("CkkT")(5)
          , i = !0;
        "find"in [] && Array(1).find((function() {
            i = !1
        }
        )),
        r(r.P + r.F * i, "Array", {
            find: function(t) {
                return o(this, t, arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void 0)
            }
        }),
        n("nGyu")("find")
    },
```

So my question is: why are these polyfills still available, even when I use a browserlist query which obviously wouldn't need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound a bit crazy but "It works on my machine" :)

I ran `npm run build` in your repo and the bundle contained the `find` polyfill - which is expected since `browserslist` is `[">0.25%", "not dead"]`.

Changing `browserslist` to `["last 2 Chrome versions"]` didn't change anything in the build - `find` was still there.

After some experimenting I noticed that any `browserslist` change was ignored.

So I tried this:

1. changed `browserslist` in `package.json`
2. ran `npm run clean` - removes `.cache` and `public`
3. ran `rm -rf node_modules`
4. ran `npm install`
5. ran `npm run build`: and `find` polyfill is gone!

Hope this works for you!

I don't have a logical explanation for this.

PS: in the docs they do recommend to `clean` after editing `package.json` - [details](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/build-caching/#clearing-cache). Reinstalling `node_modules` seems a bit extreme but it seems to solve it.

Comment: Indeed, removing node_modules is necessary. Gatsby clean is not enough. But it seems weird to have to do this, feels like a bug? Gonna investigate some more.

Comment: Feels like a bug. _Feels_ almost like the needed polyfills are added when installing node_modules.  Not sure. This is the proverbial "have you tried turning off and on again?" :)

Comment: I created an issue for this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21423